# XML Datasource From Database Column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

First, a little background:
We have been using SSRS in LocalMode for processing. We have an Object Data Source we've been using.  This Object is serialized from an XML column in the database.

We're now forced to move to Server Mode due to memory leaks in Local Mode.  As such, I'm rebuilding the reports.  The problem I've run into is that I want to pull the XML data out of the database as an object but can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I know I could create a web service or URL to provide it to the SSRS, but I want to avoid this if possible.

Is there a way to pull an XML column from a DB Data Source and get all the elements of it as the "Fields"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to query xml from on the SQL Server? There's plenty of query examples online. It still returns as a dataset but you can modify it in custom assembly to return a String that can become the query for your xml dataset inside the report.